# Unable to authenticate user using devise on fields other than email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am unable to aunthenticate user using his cell number.

All I want is, if a user is authenticated, a devise-jwt token will be send back to him.

Current, I am getting just getting error even if the cell is correct:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2023-02-02 03:06:46 +0500
Processing by Api::V1::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"users"=>{"cell"=>"4151511717"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 403)
```

routes.rb

```
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'api/v1/sessions',
      }
    end
  end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json

  private

  def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
    render json: { message: 'Logged.' }, status: :ok
  end

  def respond_to_on_destroy
    current_user ? log_out_success : log_out_failure
  end

  def log_out_success
    render json: { message: "Logged out." }, status: :ok
  end

  def log_out_failure
    render json: { message: "Logged out failure." }, status: :unauthorized
  end
end
```

devise.rb file

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  #............
  config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']
  config.authentication_keys = [:cell]
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:cell]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:cell]
  config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY']
    jwt.expiration_time = 1.day.to_i
  end
```

What else I am missing? Do I need to override create method?
If yes, how? As `resource` seems `nil` if I go for that method.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @dbugger the problem is that my api is not getting authenticated. If I try to use anything in create method, the resource is showing as nil in debugger statement on console. By error I was meant to say this: `Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 403)`

Comment: Believe the problem is with your parameters.  Should be user, not users. ```Parameters: {"user"=>{"cell"=>"4151511717"}}```